# Creating report from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Hi the following code is used to export values form Excel into a word document:

```
 Sub Createrapport()
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = Worksheets("Rapport")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheets("Rapport").Visible = True

    Dim UserName As String
    UserName = InputBox(Prompt:="Var vänligen och ange ditt namn nedan:")
    If UserName = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
    WS.Range("I1").Value = UserName
    End If

        Dim wdApp As Object
        Dim wd As Object
        Dim Tbl As Object

        On Error Resume Next
        Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        Sheets("Rapport").Activate
        Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add
        wdApp.Visible = True

        'sidhuvud
        wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
        With wd
            Set Tbl = .tables.Add(wdApp.Selection.Range, 2, 3, wdWord8TableBehavior)
            Tbl.cell(1, 1).Range.Text = WS.Range("K4").Text
            Tbl.cell(1, 2).Range.Text = WS.Range("L4").Text
            Tbl.cell(1, 3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2 'wdAlignParagraphRight
            Tbl.cell(1, 3).Range.Text = WS.Range("I1").Text
            Tbl.cell(2, 1).Range.Text = WS.Range("K5").Text
            Tbl.cell(2, 3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2 'wdAlignParagraphRight
            Tbl.cell(2, 3).Range.Text = WS.Range("M5").Text
        End With
        wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0

        'sidnummer
        'Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True

        '***** copy image from cell H11:M411 in Excel
        Worksheets("Rapport").Range("H11:M41").Copy
        '***** past image at the current position in Word
        wdApp.Selection.Paste

    Set rng = Worksheets("Rapport").Range("A1:E203")

    rng.Copy
       With wd.Range
            .collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
            .InsertParagraphAfter                   'Lägg till rad
            .collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
            .PasteSpecial False, False, True        'Pasta som Enhanced Metafile
       End With
       Sheets("Rapport").Visible = False
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Set newDoc = Documents.Add
Set myTable = _
    newDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, _
    NumColumns:=3)
myTable.Cell(2, 1).SetWidth _
    ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1.5), _
    RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone

    End Sub
```

The report obtained then looks like this:

[image: sample picture]

How can I make the values fit within the margins of the word document? this is the prt that does it and it is "InchesToPoints(1.5)" which bugs:

```
Set newDoc = Documents.Add
    Set myTable = _
        newDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, _
        NumColumns:=3)
    myTable.Cell(2, 1).SetWidth _
        ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1.5), _
        RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
Set newDoc = Documents.Add
        Set myTable = _
    newDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, _
    NumColumns:=3)
'***** Word constant wdPreferredWidthPercent = 2
myTable.PreferredWidthType = 2
myTable.PreferredWidth = 100
    myTable.Cell(2, 1).SetWidth _
        ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1.5), _
        RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
```

Comment: I'm afraid `help rewriting my code` is not what SO is about. Try to ask specific questions about specific problems. General tips: try debugging your code by stepping through it line by line to see where it goes wrong (using F8), try searching [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[word-vba]set+table+width) or [elsewhere](https://www.google.se/#q=word+vba+set+table+width), try the macro recorder. Then come back to SO with any problems, error messages etc.

Comment: That said, the first section in [this link](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/FitTableToPage.htm) should get you started. You set the table width to 100% of the page width. See separate answer. It says Word 2000 but works in newer versions of Word as well. I found it using google and tried it in Word 2010! :)

Comment: Hi Olle. I will rewrite  my above post to as SO prefers it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found through the magic of [google](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/FitTableToPage.htm):

```
Selection.Tables(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
Selection.Tables(1).PreferredWidth = 100
```

Says Word 2000, tried and works in Word 2010.

(In your case you probably have to add `wdApp.` before the `Selection` object, and make sure that `Selection` points to the place in the document where the table is.)

**EDIT**

My code sample updated to match your updated code:

```
'***** Word constant wdPreferredWidthPercent = 2
myTable.PreferredWidthType = 2
myTable.PreferredWidth = 100
```

Place it right after the `Set myTable =` line.

**EDIT 2**

The underscore in VBA means that the one code line extends over several lines, so you can't put code in between (if that is what's not working).

Code sample in context:

```
Set myTable = _
    newDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, _
    NumColumns:=3)
'***** Word constant wdPreferredWidthPercent = 2
myTable.PreferredWidthType = 2
myTable.PreferredWidth = 100
```

**EDIT 3**

```
Set newDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
Set myTable = _
    newDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=wdApp.Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, _
    NumColumns:=3)

'***** Word constant wdPreferredWidthPercent = 2
myTable.PreferredWidthType = 2
myTable.PreferredWidth = 100

myTable.Cell(2, 1).SetWidth _
    ColumnWidth:=wdApp.InchesToPoints(1.5), _
    RulerStyle:=0 '*****wdAdjustNone
```

Comment: I try usign the code above but It says "Value outside interval", thank you.

Comment: @RinorM Try the updated code. You had to make sure `Selection.Tables(1)` pointed to the right `Table` object, but since you alreadey have the `myTable` reference, use that instead. Also, you probably need to replace the constant `wdPreferredWidthPercent` with its numeric value, since you ware working from Excel using late binding.

Comment: I am having trouble to place the code right after, Set myTable line,could you assist me with that also? thank you.

Comment: @RinorM Updated again. Please tell exactly what the problem is, `having trouble to place the code right after` doesn't say much, which leaves me guessing.

Comment: Ok sorry, I have edited the code above, but the problem occurs in the line which says  **ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1.5), _**  and it says "Sub or function have not been defined"

Comment: @RinorM My guess is you have copied a macro from Word to Excel? If so, you are using late binding you need to "translate" it so that Excel understands all references to objects and constants (because of the late binding, google it). See Edit #3, note _all_ the changes.

Comment: And again, you are now asking many questions in one - they should really be separated into individual questions. :)

Comment: Yes that is what I have done. Ok thank you for the help. I will try and make the code work somehow. And if I have any further question I will post it in a new post :)

Comment: By the way, the code above, gives 2 word documents. The first one is that is copied from Excel and the other one is blank?

Comment: Part of learning VBA (or any programming language) is be able to understand code. ;) If you read your code sample, you have two lines which state `wdApp.Documents.Add`: one stores a reference to the new document in variable `wd`, the other one stores another reference in `newDoc`. In other words, you have told Word to create two documents. Remove the line which creates the second document and replace any references to `newDoc` with `wd` in order to keep working on the first doc!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myTable.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
```

of if you are late binding:

```
myTable.AutoFitBehavior 2
```

This will autofit the table within the word document margins.
Is this what you're trying?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do. When i run your sudgestion I get an error message that says : "Object needed, runtimeerror 424". Thank you for your time

Comment: You need to properly declare your table variable. In your first code, it should be `Tbl.AutoFitBehavior 2`. `mytable` should be a table object.